# Why it does not jump into if sentence? C# #UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have this HangMan game and i got problems. When user clicks on alphabet button, it wont jump into that if-sentence which i got in my code. "Current" variable is a string and the button content is a letter and i want to know if that guessing word contains that letter, which user clicks on. Even if i debug that code, i don't get the "current" variable(guessing word)in that Guessing method. Thanks for all!

```
    public sealed partial class Hangman : Page
{
    private string[] words;
    private int WrongGuesses = 0;
    private string copyCurrent;
    private string current;
    public Hangman()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        loadWords();
        DisplayTheWord();
        Hangman_OnLoaded();
    }

    private void loadWords()
    {
        string[] ReadWords = File.ReadAllLines("EnglishWords.txt");
        words = new string[ReadWords.Length];
    }
    private string[] images =
    {
        "/Assets/hang1.png", "/Assets/hang2.png", "/Assets/hang3.png",
        "/Assets/hang4.png", "/Assets/hang5.png"
    };

    public void PlayAgain_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WrongGuesses = 0;
        BitmapImage Hangman2 = new BitmapImage();
        Uri URL = new Uri(BaseUri, images[WrongGuesses]);
        Hangman2.UriSource = URL;
        picture.Source = Hangman2;
        string[] ReadWords = File.ReadAllLines("EnglishWords.txt");
        int NextNumber = new Random().Next(words.Length);
        copyCurrent = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < ReadWords[NextNumber].Length; i++)
        {
            copyCurrent += "_" + "   ";
        }
        CopiedWord.Text = copyCurrent;
    }

    public void DisplayTheWord()
    {
        WrongGuesses = 0;
        BitmapImage Hangman2 = new BitmapImage();
        Uri URL = new Uri(BaseUri, images[WrongGuesses]);
        Hangman2.UriSource = URL;
        picture.Source = Hangman2;
        string[] ReadWords = File.ReadAllLines("EnglishWords.txt");   
        int NextNumber = new Random().Next(words.Length);             
        copyCurrent = ""; 
        current = ReadWords[NextNumber];                          

        for (int i = 0; i < ReadWords[NextNumber].Length; i++)
        {
            copyCurrent += "_" + "   ";                            
        }
        CopiedWord.Text = copyCurrent;                            
    }
    public void Hangman_OnLoaded()
    {
        const int btnSize = 35;                                  
        var c = 0;                                               
        for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++)                           
        {
            var btn = new Button {                              
                Content = (char) i,                              
            };                                                    
            btn.Width = btn.Height = btnSize;                    
            var margin = btn.Margin;                              
            margin.Left = c += 37;                                
            btn.Margin = margin;                                 
            GridMain.Children.Add(btn);                          
            btn.Click += Guessing;                               
        }

    }
    private void Guessing(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button choice = sender as Button;
        var ltr = choice.Content.ToString();
        if (current.Contains(ltr))                              // it wont jump into this if sentence                 
        {
                char[] temp = copyCurrent.ToCharArray();           
                char[] find = current.ToCharArray();               
                char guessChar = ltr.ElementAt(0);                 
            for (int index = 0; index < find.Length; index++)      
                {                                                  
                    if (find[index]== guessChar)                   
                    {                                              
                        temp[index] = guessChar;                   
                    }                                              
                }                                                  
                copyCurrent = new string(temp);                   
            }
            else
            {
                WrongGuesses++;                                    
            }
            if (WrongGuesses < 6)
            {
                //picture.Source = muudab pilti
            }
```

Comment: If you have debugged this code then you should know what are the values of _ltr_ and _current_. So just ask yourself in which point things are not going as you expect

Comment: I get the value of ltr, but i don't get the current value.

Answer (score 0):

> Why it does not jump into if sentence?

No jump is because your `current` variable is null or it doesn't contain the `Itr` you give.

> I get the value of ltr, but i don't get the current value

I have tested your code about getting `current` value and there is nothing wrong with the code itself. But `current` is a string that got from a random line from `EnglishWords.txt`, if the random line has no content, it will contain nothing. So please check the text file if it has blank lines and the result of `current = ReadWords[NextNumber];`.